# Finish previous 2 activities on button clicked android but not home screen

Tags: android, android-activity

My android app has 4 screen.

- Screen 1 (Home Screen)
- Screen 2
- Screen 3
- Screen 4
- screen 1 starts screen 2 and
- screen 2 starts screen 3 and
- screen 3 starts screen 4 after then
- screen 4 go on screen 2
- screen 2 back press go on screen 1

I have added upload some data on screen 4. When data uploaded successfully so go on Screen 2 And When press back so go on screen 1(Home Screen) and after back finish.
Screen 1 -> Screen 2 -> Screen 3 ->Screen 4 (go with finish) -> Screen 2(on back press) -> Screen 1(on back press finish app)

but when i use finish method on screen 4

- Screen 4(finish and go ) Screen 2
- Screen 2(back press go ) Screen 3
- Screen 3(back press go ) Screen 2
- Screen 2(back press go ) Screen 1 then finish

is there any way to finish screen 3 and screen 2 from screen 4

Comment: read about launcher modes and activity backstack and Tasks

Comment: just override 'onBackPressed' method in each activity required

Comment: is there any link to read launcher modes and activity backstack

Comment: thanks bro i've got the solution and code is    --->                                                                                                               
                                                                                                         
             finish();
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);;
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(mIntent);

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` when going to Screen 4 from Screen 3, you will get results as you want.

Comment: yes i've used finish method on screen 4 but after this screen 2 go on screen 3 then scree 3 again go screen 2 and then screen 1 and then finish

Comment: Use finish in screen three as well.

Comment: how can do this on screen 4 how to finish screen 3

Comment: In screen 3, when you are going to start screen 4 in screen3 call finish()

Comment: but when data not uploaded on Screen 4 User can also come  back in reverse 4->3->2->1->finish

Comment: is there any way to finish screen 3 and screen 2 from screen 4